# Google Visualization BarFormat

Tags: google-visualization

Hi I am trying to use two different foramtters for my DataTable. They get the base value from two different text input fields.

The ArrowFormatter is working, but how can I refresh the base value if the user changes the input in the text field?

and the Barformatter doesn´t work. It only shows html code in the table.

var formatterEnergy = new google.visualization.ArrowFormat({
          base: document.getElementById("energy_input").value,
          allowHtml: true,
      });
      formatterEnergy.format(data, 3);

```
  var formatterPower = new google.visualization.BarFormat({
      base: document.getElementById("power_input").value,
      allowHtml: true,
  });
  formatterPower.format(data, 6);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  var drawOptions = {
    showRowNumber: false,
    allowHtml: true,
  };
```

Comment: I added the allowHtml attribute to the table options and now it works.

Comment: But i still don´t know how to refresh the base value.

Comment: sounds like you'll need to listen for the change event on the text field, then re-create the formatter with the new base value, format the data, and re-draw the chart...